# How to remove external IP from GCP cluster in Terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, cluster-computing

I deployed clusters, but my clusters exposed external and internal IPs, but I want to ged rid of external ip while deploying in terraform, how can I do that?

Comment: Please provide more information on what exactly you are trying to do (eg. what module you are using to deploy your cluster and what configuration you currently use)

If you want your cluster to NOT have external ip associated, you need to configure your terraform module appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

You need use this key `service_external_ips_config`. Follow this [link](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/container_cluster#service_external_ips_config)

Comment: Link-only answers are generally [frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/204922) on Stack Overflow. In time it is possible for links to atrophy and become unavailable, meaning that your answer is useless to users in the future. It would be best if you could provide the general details of your answer in your actual post, citing your link as a reference.